# python offline plotly saves the file always in default file name how to save in differrent name

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have the following code to graph using plotly offline .

```
import plotly
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
#import plotly.plotly as py
......
......
......

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig, filename = 'result.html')
plot(fig,show_link = True)
```

This stores the html output in a local drive where the python files is available but it always stores with the default file name called temp-plot.html

This overwrites the file all time . How to save the file in desired name in html format using offline plotly

what is the change in the code that would resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same args for `plot`:

```
plot(fig,show_link = True, filename = 'result.html')
```